# elastic string script makes flash crash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, removechild

I'm in over my head in this AS3 project.

I'm no expert in actionscript and certainly not in AS3 but I managed to create (with help from this: http://swamy-techtalk.blogspot.com/2011/07/elastic-string-to-mouse-pointer-effect.html) a eleastic string effect from a point to a draggable movieclip.

Problem is the script seems to crash flash or the browser when I test it. (Not right away just when I'm playing around with the movieclip)

Sinse I'm in over my head in the script I compiled I'm not exactly sure whats wrong.
A bit of google research hinted that it might have something to do with removeChildAt() wich I changed from removeChildAt(0) to removeChildAt(1) to prevent it from removing my movieclip.

Hope somebody has the patience to read through my script to see what I did wrong.

Example here: http://www.madsringblom.dk/flash/pullstring.html  (beware it might crash your browser)
Code below:

```
Object(this).leaf_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler); 
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler); 

var origX:int = Object(this).leaf_mc.x + 1; 
var origY:int = Object(this).leaf_mc.y + 2; 
var pullbackX:int = Object(this).leaf_mc.x; 
var pullbackY:int = Object(this).leaf_mc.y; 
var dragging:Boolean = false; 

//speed of pulling and rotating back when stop dragging. 

var speed:int = 15; 
var addX:int = 2 
var addY:int = 3 

function mouseDownHandler(e:MouseEvent):void 
{ 
    var obj = e.target; 
    obj.startDrag(); 
    dragging = true; 

} 

function mouseUpHandler(e:MouseEvent):void 
{  
    var obj = e.target; 
    Object(this).leaf_mc.stopDrag(); 
    dragging = false; 

} 

import flash.display.*; 
import flash.events.MouseEvent; 
import flash.events.Event; 

var haschild:Boolean = false; 
var gotonodes:Array = new Array(); 
var currentnodes:Array = new Array(); 

var posX:int = Object(this).leaf_mc.x + addX; 
var posY:int = Object(this).leaf_mc.y + addY; 
gotonodes = Interpolate(posX,posY,origX,origY,25); 
currentnodes = gotonodes; 
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onmove1); 

function onmove1(e:Event)
{ 
    for (var node = 0; node < gotonodes.length - 1; node++)
    { 
        currentnodes[node].xco=currentnodes[node].xco+(gotonodes[node].xco-currentnodes[node].xco)/(node*node/30+1); 
        currentnodes[node].yco=currentnodes[node].yco+(gotonodes[node].yco-currentnodes[node].yco)/(node*node/30+1); 
    }

    var posX:int = Object(this).leaf_mc.x + addX; 
    var posY:int = Object(this).leaf_mc.y + addY; 
    gotonodes=Interpolate(posX,posY,origX,origY,25); 

    // pull leaf_mc back to starting point when released. And rotate back. 

    if (dragging == false)
    { 
        Object(this).leaf_mc.x-=(Object(this).leaf_mc.x-pullbackX)/speed; 
        Object(this).leaf_mc.y-=(Object(this).leaf_mc.y-pullbackY)/speed; 
        Object(this).leaf_mc.rotation+=Object(this).leaf_mc.rotation/speed; 
    } 

    // rotating the leaf_mc according to the point (origX,origY) 

    var theX:int = origX - Object(this).leaf_mc.x; 
    var theY:int = (origY - Object(this).leaf_mc.y) * -1; 
    var angle = Math.atan(theY/theX)/(Math.PI/180); 
    Math.atan( -5 / 10) / (Math.PI / 180); 

    if (theX < 0) 
    { 
        angle += 180; 
    } 

    if (theX >= 0 && theY < 0) 
    { 
        angle += 360; 
    } 

    Object(this).leaf_mc.rotation = (angle*-1) + 90; 

    DrawNodes(currentnodes); 

} 

function FindAngle(x1, x2, y1, y2):Number 
{ 
    return Math.atan2(y2-y1, x2-x1); 
}; 

function Distance(x1, x2, y1, y2):Number
{ 
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2-x1,2)+Math.pow(y2-y1,2)); 
} 

function Interpolate(x1, y1, x2, y2, n):Array
{ 
    var dist= Distance(x1,x2,y1,y2); 
    var ang = FindAngle(x1,x2,y1,y2); 
    var points = [];

    for (var l = 0; l <= dist; l += dist / n)
    { 
        var x3 =x1+l*Math.cos(ang); 
        var y3 = y1+l*Math.sin(ang); 
        points.push({xco:x3,yco:y3}); 
    } 

    points.push( { xco:x1, yco:y1 } ); 

    return points; 

} 

function DrawNodes(array):void
{ 
    if(haschild) 
    { 
        this.removeChildAt(1); 
        haschild=false; 
    } 

    var shape:Shape = new Shape(); 
    shape.graphics.lineStyle(1,0x331100,40); 
    shape.graphics.moveTo(array[0].xco, array[0].yco);

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++)
    { 
        shape.graphics.lineTo(array[i].xco,array[i].yco); 
    } 

    shape.graphics.beginFill(0xFBFFA4,1); 
    shape.graphics.drawCircle(array[0].xco,array[0].yco,1); 
    shape.graphics.endFill(); 
    this.addChild(shape); 
    haschild = true;

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "crash"? It just seems to hang after a while (`top` shows 100% CPU usage).

Comment: Dude, you *seriously* need to learn about keeping your code clean.  This is a mess.

Answer (score 0):

Where is this code placed? From what you pasted, I'm thinking on the stage.

A `stop();` somewhere in the script might be a start and help quite a bit - otherwise the Flash movie will loop, and every time it hits this frame (every frame if you only have one), you'll add new event handlers etc. Eventually you'll run out of memory, and the `onmove1` event handler will eat up your CPU, running 50 times per frame after 50 frames, 200 times after 200 frames etc.